# Is there some pitfalls if I define aliases for `cdr` and `car` functions?

Tags: elisp, aliases

I'm often obliged to read the documentation before using `cdr` and `car` functions. Is there pitfalls I should be aware of before aliasing those functions in my init file? Like:

```
(defalias 'head 'car)
(defalias 'tail 'cdr)
```

Comment: But then how will you ever learn to use `cadr`, `cadar`, and `cddar`?

Comment: @abo-abo You're right, those name are just not user friendly nor easy to associate with what the function is doing :\

Comment: FYI, along with `first` you also get `second`, `third`, ..., `tenth`, which covers some of those functions. I have no problem with `car` and `cdr`, but counting `a`s and `d`s gets unwieldy pretty quickly...

Comment: @phils definitely

Comment: On the contrary (and this might have been @abo-abo's point; dunno): `cadr` etc. are **very** mnemonic and give you an instant picture of just what each of them does.  (On the other hand, access macros named specifically for what they mean for your application are often a better idea.)

Comment: If you are just accessing elements of a list in a flat, linear manner (i.e., not digging into tree structure), then function `nth` is a good substitute. It is the generic version of `first`, `second`, etc.

Comment: @Drew mnemonic? I'm probably blind :( or still being struggling to do the difference between car & cdr, I wont be able to see the mnemonic?!

Comment: Maybe you are; dunno. What can I say? ;-) I see an access path through a tree - a very straightforward & simple picture. Maybe something like [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=CIYUAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=cadr+cdar+cadar+lisp&source=bl&ots=0HG6a1X7E1&sig=N2pGHcCCg0B0vP9Ow4J0RVqY4vM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HCu3VN3fJsugyASvo4LIDw&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=cadr%20cdar%20cadar%20lisp&f=false) will help. Maybe not. If you don't define meaningful access macros (which is best), do you really prefer `(tail (tail (head (head (tail (head xs))))))` to `(cddaadar xs)`?

Comment: I was trying to say that `cadr`, `cadar` and `cddar` are extremely intuitive and mnemonic. `c` and `r` are just filler, `a` means "go left", `d` means "go right". Easy as pie

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd suggest that you `(require 'cl)` and then use `first` and `rest` instead. They already exist, and are the standard alternative names.

They also get expanded to the actual `car` and `cdr` byte-code at compilation, whereas your custom aliases would not. (Not that you can't *make* them -- see the definition of `cl--defalias` -- but I think sticking to the standard aliases is a better idea.)

Comment: For what it's worth, the cleaned up `cl-lib` has `cl-first` and `cl-rest`.

Comment: Yeah; I just couldn't bring myself to suggest those ones as being *better* alternative names.

Comment: Fair enough -- thought I'd bring it up since `cl-lib` is (I think?) the successor to `cl`.